# How does Resource (like ngresource module in AngularJS) used/work in Angular 2?

Tags: rest, angular, resources, crud, ngresource

I want to use Resource for getting value from REST API. I know that there are some way to attain my goal. But I want to use Resource in Angular 2 like ngresource module in AngularJS. I couldn't found any documentation, useful example or article for provide that.

Answer (score 1):

[Restangular for Angular 2 and higher versions](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/)